# Managing data via Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase database for a mobile app that displays courses and etc. Currently, there is no login system. Sometime in the future, I'm planning to add a web application as well.

What is the best way to manage the data that comes through Firebase Database into the mobile app?

Currently I'm manually entering the keys/values into the Firebase system (really stupid I know). Should I make a private web app or some something to POST/GET/UPDATE this data?

How do companies handle this?

Edit:

My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Firstname Lastname",
    "about": "about the professor",
    "phone": "(408) 333-2222",
    "email": "aaa@aaa.com",
    "hobbies": "swimming, etc etc",
    "profile_picture": "url",
    "courses": {}
}
```

Comment: Manually entering data is a valid, simple approach until a certain point. Most apps indeed end up with an admin front-end over time, which can often be a simple web page.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding data into a Firebase database is not wrong. It is the simplest way in which you can add data. According to the complexity of your database you can choose what to create. If your database is as simplest as your provided `JSON` sample is, than it's not a big deal doing that. But if your application grows in the future and you'll need to add constant data that this option will not help you anymore. So to simplify things, you'll need to create as also Frank said, a simple web page with an front-end admin to manage your data easier.

Hope it helps.